# how to amend formatting of output

Tags: powershell

when I do the below I get the format as "@{xxx}"...how do I just get the computer description and none of the the other formatting around it?

> $CompDes = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem |Select
>   Description
>
> Write-Host "Computer Description $CompDes"

Output:

```
Computer Description @{Description=TESING_SERVER}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$CompDes = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem | Select -exp Description
Write-Host "Computer Description $CompDes"
```

`-exp` is short for `-ExpandProperty`. It gets the value of the specified property.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
$CompDes = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem | Foreach-Object {$_.Description}
```